# how to change hashbang to auto detect script type

Tags: shell-script, shell

I have the following script:

```
 1 #!/usr/bin/env sh
 2 #calculate number of tests we will run
 3 lines="$(cat /etc/crontabs/root|wc -l)"
 4 tests="$(($lines - 2))"
 5
 6 echo "1..$tests"
 7 counter=1
 8 etc.... does other stuff
```

On line 1, i'm trying to code it in such a way so that i do not have to type "sh " to launch it. 
Previously, the hashbang looked like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

and the code would work but you have to tell it which exe to use to launch it.

I'd like to now try to change it so that the user doesn't have to know what kind of a script it is.  I think i've done something wrong because when I try to run my script, I get the following error:

```
lab-1:/tmp# crontab_test       
-ash: crontab_test: not found
```

Can you tell me where I have strayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hashbang path looks fine.

Is your script in the `/tmp` directory?

The `/tmp` directory is (usually) not in your `$PATH` so you have to specify the directory on the command line. You can use `./` for the current directory:

```
./crontab_test
```

Some systems have the current directory `.` in the `$PATH`, but that is considered a bit doubtful from a security standpoint.

Comment: doh!  so simple.  Thanks!  will accept as answer as soon as the site lets me